# Rename USB network interface based on location

Tags: udev

I'm managing a group of laptops and I'd like each of them to assign the same name to their USB network interface for easy management.  Most of them assign enp0s20u1 and I've written my management script based on that, but some of them assign enp3s0u1.  All of the udev rule solutions I can find require me to specify the MAC address of the network interface, but I want the interfaces to be interchangeable.  Can I somehow rename enp3s0u1 to enp0s20u1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This udev rule does the trick (/etc/udev/rules.d/76-network.rules):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", ENV{ID_NET_NAME_PATH}=="enp3s0u1", NAME="enp0s20u1"
```

https://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/handbook/handbook-amd64.xml?part=4&chap=2#doc_chap4